# WCF Global(.asax) Behavior

Tags: wcf, rest, c#-4.0

I want to create a global option that when a REST call contains &format=json to output the response as a JSON string.

If I enter the following String in my method it works:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
```

However, if I add this line, anywhere in my Global.asax file, I get a nullException for Current Context:

```
String format = "";

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["format"] != null)
  format = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["format"];

if (String.Equals("json", format, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json;
```

The exception is triggered here:

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current
```

Anyone know how I can add this functionality globally (WCF)?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to add this to the Global.asax. I just need it to be global so it will affect all 450 operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own DispatchMessageInspector to WCF processing pipeline via service behavior.   [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx?ppud=4) is how to do that.

To apply behavior via config file at first you should derive new class from BehaviorExtensionElement and override members BehaviorType and CreateBehavior.
Then add to config section similar to that (with your full type name)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="myBehavior" type="SomeNamespace.MyBehaviorExtensionElement, AssemblyName,
                Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
       </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and that

```
<behaviors>
    <behavior configurationName="myServiceBehavior">
        <myBehavior />            
    </behavior>
</behaviors>
```

Finally apply this configuration to your service.

Comment: I created this, but it's just ignoring its existence. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe behavior wasn't properly attached to the service. You can show how you did that, and I think I will be able to help.

Comment: I think the problem is adding it to the web.config
What do I need to add, so it stops ignoring me?

Comment: Parser Error Message: Invalid element in configuration. The extension 'myBehavior' does not derive from correct extension base type 'System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement'.

Comment: Check that your extension type is specified correctly. Is 'myBehavior' the name of your extension class?

Comment: namespace Wadja.API
{
    public class customExtensionsBehavior : IDispatchMessageInspector, IServiceBehavior {}
}

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  It was ignoring me because I attached the behavior to a service, and I was testing outside of the Service1 spectrum